# Facebook Graph API - GraphMethodException error code 100

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is how I have been using graph API to get public info of an user:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/{user_id}
```

It was working for almost all the users except this with uid 1283218355

```
http://graph.facebook.com/1283218355
```

So when I try this link, it gives error with code 100.

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request.",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Could be that that person turned off Facebook Platform

Comment: If you mean that he could have deactivated his FB profile then no, I can visit his profile http://facebook.com/1283218355 which means his FB profile is active.

Comment: No I meant that he de-activated Facebook Platform which means you can't see him in the API